# sort objects with several parameters - symfony2

Tags: symfony, sorting, doctrine

I want to display a list of objects ordered by a parameter that depends of several fields of the entity.

I have created an entity, let's call it Object for instance, which has an id and 2 integers as fields. I work with Symfony 2 and Doctrine as ORM.

```
  `/**
 * Object
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="object")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ObjectRepository")
 */
 class Object
 {
     /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="field1", type="int")
      */
     private $field1;

     /**
      * @var int
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="field2", type="int")
      */
     private $field2;
 }
```

Now I would like to get the top-5 instances of Object from my database ordered by, for example, the average between field1 and field2, to display them in a twig template.

I know I can use this:

```
$list = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Object')->findAll();
```

to get a list of all existing instances of Object in the DB, but although it might be a relatively simple question to experimented Symfony programmers, I have no idea about how to order it by avg(field1,field2).

Comment: this is simple forward php sorting: http://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method in your repository that builds a query containing a special `ORDER BY` clause and that limits the number of results to 5. It could look like this:

```
class ObjectRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    /* ... other methods ... */

    public function retrieveTopObjects($limit = 5)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')->orderBy('(o.field1 + o.field2) / 2', 'DESC');
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

If you would like to have the score used to sort entities along with your objects, you would need to add `$qb->addSelect('(o.field1 + o.field2) / 2 AS score')` and then use `$qb->orderBy('score', 'DESC')` instead of the expression shown above.

In such a case, you would end up with a mixed result as explained [in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#pure-and-mixed-results).